# Firebase Crash Reporting to Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using **Firebase Crash Reporting** in my android application. I got this warning message (Your Crash Reporting dashboard will no longer be accessible on September 9, 2018) in **Firebase Crash Reporting Dashboard**. So I am planing to add **Crashlytics** error reporting in my app and update in Play store.

If current users don't update the app(App with Crashlytics) from Playstore, what happens to error reporting after September 9, 2018 for that old apps?

Comment: Paul from Firebase here. Error reporting after September 9, 2018 through Firebase Crash Reporting will no longer be available.

Comment: @buser - Hi Paul, Is there any option to get error reports in Crashlytics Error Reporting, other than force updating the app for current user?

Comment: No, the user needs to update to a newer version for crashes to still be processed. The 6 month notice provided was to try and help give you and developers time to update and ship out versions of your app with Crashlytics in it to minimize any potential crashes not reported.